# PHP about include 404 page not found

Tags: php, file, dynamic

I have php script can not include 404 page,
I know you can in.htaccess but i want in php script offices.
How to turn the 404 into this script?

```
Example php script is dynamic include
    $url = '';
        if (!empty($_GET['folder'])) {
            $url .= $_GET['folder'] . '/';
    } 
    if (!empty($_GET['file'])) {
    $url .= $_GET['file'] . 'php';

    include $url; 

    }
    else 
    {
    include('pages/home.php');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> header('Location: pages/home.php');

This will redirect to the 404 page

Comment: how to include in my script

Comment: Are you sure about the file path to the 404 page?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the else statement where home.php is called now. All the files they do not exist are now the home.php file....... Maybe you also have to change the folder which is called before the slash

Answer (score 0):

This is how you tell the browser in PHP that you have a 404 error:

```
<?php
#   Send to the browser a 404 error code
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');

#   Display your 404 page
include('httpErrors/404.php');
?>
```